# Mysql Entityframework throws exception "Facet 'Precision' must not be specified for type 'datetime'"

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am using MYSQL and EF5(DB first) with connector/net 6.8.3.0. Everything works fine on my local machine but when I upload it to server it throws exception "Facet 'Precision' must not be specified for type 'datetime'".

Please let me know what is the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precision for datetime is added with MYSQL version 5.6 and I have generated the entities with latest MYSQL, so by default precision is added to the ssdl.

But on my server older version of MYSQL server was installed. This is the reason why it was throwing the exception.

Now with MYSQL server 5.6 we can have datetime(5) where 5 is the precision.

So we can have microsecond for datetime in MYSQL.

Answer (score 1):

I too have been getting the "Facet 'Precision' must not be specified for type 'datetime'" error after publishing, but the cause of my problem differs from the OP's.

### My Personal Solution

I have two independent servers: '*server1*' with the EF5 web app, '*server2*' with the database *server1* references.  Debugging the app on my local machine was no problem; but after I published to *server1* the app kept crashing while trying to load.  After much searching and testing I narrowed it down to either a configuration issue either with my application or MySQL.  Finding this post (*thank you kindly, user3275493, for answering your own question*), I checked *server2*'s MySQL config but alas it was **already running MySQL Server 5.6**.  Just to be thorough (in reality this took me several days to realize), I decided to check MySQL Connecter and discovered that **my local machine's was version 6.8.3 while *server1*'s was version 5.6**.  After I updated Connector, I published my web app and it ran without flaw!

### Simple Explanation

Not only will this error be caused by a MySQL version disagreement between Entity Framework and MySQL Server, but also between Entity Framework and MySQL Connector!